# Instantaneous frequency not plotting correctly in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, frequency

I'm trying to convert square wave data to instantaneous frequency and plot against time. It works correctly for one data set, but three others are plotting as shown in the image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/iuL648o.png]

Time is linear, so it shouldn't be plotting like that. Anyone have any ideas as to what's going on? I'm using the following code:

```
ddiff = diff(flow(:,1));
locations = find(ddiff(1:end-1,1)>0.1 & ddiff(2:end,1) <=0.1);
for z = 2:length(locations)
    inst_freq(z-1) = 1/(time(locations(z))-time(locations(z-1)));
    freq_time(z-1) = time(locations(z));
end
plot(freq_time,inst_freq)
```

Edit: Subsequent to the comments below, I realised the locations variable was not the same size as inst_freq of freq_time. This is because the code is part of another loop, and earlier iterations had longer variables. Clearing the variables at the end of every loop fixed the problem.

Comment: Try plotting the variable `freq_time` on its own.  I expect that it will not be monotonic.  Also, where does the variable `time` come from?

Comment: Ah! That does seem to be the problem. I'd tried plotting time, which was as expected, but didn't think about freq_time. Any ideas as to why that's happening? Time and flow are both recorded data. 
http://i.imgur.com/KetRtIX.png

Cheers!

Comment: What is the size of `time`?  You are indexing it with a single integer, so if it has more than one non-singleton dimension you might get strange results.

Comment: It's a 50000x1 double; I thought that should be ok.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. So, if `freq_time` is not monotonic, then it suggests that either `time` or `locations` is not monotonic.  That is what you need to resolve.

Comment: I've tried plotting both of them, and they're linear, so I'm not sure what's going on. I'll have to think about it some more. Thanks a lot for your help.